# How can I use a special independent Random in unity via c#

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine

I want use a independent Random instance, so that I can set a special seed for this independent Random. I just want only this Random's seed to be special, and the global Random.seed to be normal.

I try this:

```
public Random newRandom = new Random();
```

But I found that the new Random does not have a function to set seed, because `UnityEngine.Random.seed` is a static member. How can I do it?

And if I set a seed successfully, I'd like to use newRandom.range(int, int) to get new value.

Comment: what's wrong with public Random newRandom = new Random(seed);

Comment: I just try public Random newRandom = new Random(1); But the unity tell me "The type `UnityEngine.Random' does not contain a constructor that takes `1' arguments"

Comment: You should use `System.Random`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that you confuse `UnityEngine.Random` class and `System.Random` class. It's unfortunate that they have the same name and a lot of developers use `UnityEngine` and `System` by default (it also causes confusion for `Object` class).

`UnityEngine.Random` is completely static. So, if you write `new Random()`, and you don't get a compile error, it means that you have `using System;` in the file, and the compiler actually understands you as `new System.Random()`.

Using `System.Random()` is actually a pretty good idea for such a situation; just be aware that `UnityEngine.Random` and `System.Random` are not guaranteed to produce the same values from the same seed. And of course, if you want to specify a custom seed, you should do it [with the constructor `new Random(int seed)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww(v=vs.110).aspx), just as @GreenEyedAndy suggested.

Answer (score 1):

**Unity and Mono each have a Random Class.**

The [Unity Random](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.html) allows you to set a specific seed using `Random.seed`, but cannot be instantiated.

The [Mono Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx) can be instantiated with a special seed.

You should probably use `System.Random` for your use case.

Just write:

```
public System.Random newRandom = new System.Random(seed);
```

> You should write `System.Random` because otherwise, even if you used the `System` namespace, you will have an ambiguity and the compiler will complain.

Be careful, since it does not work exactly the same way.